# Edit Windows Boot Loader from Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows-7, bootloader

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, and Windows 7. I accidentally removed the Windows option from the Windows Boot Loader using EasyBCD. I do not know how to access the windows boot loader configuration files. I am a novice, but I can execute commands at the terminal.

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info ).